# Outputting the same string input

Tags: mips

Suppose that I want to output the same string I inserted , I would use the following

```
main:

la $a0,buffer #allocate space for $a0

li $v0,8 #read the string input 
syscall

li $v0, 4 #print the string input 
syscall

li $v0,10 #stop the program
syscall
```

Well, that wont work and I have to add

```
li $a1,..
```

and I don't know why ?

Comment: _"that wont work"_ In what way does it not work? Also, you mention that you added some code to try to fix the problem, but not what _exactly_ it was you added or where you added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the MARS/spim syscall doc [here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html).

For syscall 8 you need to specify a buffer address in `$a0` and a length in `$a1`. My guess is the code above doesn't work because the program starts off with `$a1` preset to zero meaning that you will read in 0 bytes.

In addition, your comment on the first line is wrong. Using `la` does not allocate space. This should be done in the `text` segment where I assume the `buffer` label is defined. Using `la` only loads the address of the label `buffer` into a register.

Comment: I defined buffer in the .data where  buffer: .space number. I thought reserves some space for String input.

Comment: Yep. That's right. It's just the comment doesn't match with the first line.